# How to solve - syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Tags: c++, list, syntax, linked-list

I have been receiving this error and it appears to be too vague for a Google search so I am handing it over to you! I am trying to create a linked list object that holds Account objects.

```
#include "Customer.h"
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include "Mortgage.h"
#include "CurrentAcc.h"
#include "JuniorAcc.h"
#include "transaction.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


string name;
string address;
string telNo;
char gender;
string dateOfBirth;
list<Account> accList;  // Error
list<Mortgage> mortList;  //Error
```

I feel that I am not properly declaring my Linked Lists but cannot think of how else to do it.

The next piece of code I feel is as a result of my bad declaration.

```
void Customer::openCurrentAccount(int numb, double bal, int cl, string type, double Interest){
Current acc(numb,bal,cl,type,Interest); //Error - Expression must have class type.
accList.add(acc);
}
```

And here is the creation of my Linked List class .h file.

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class node;

template <class T>

class list
{

public:
list() { head = tail = NULL; }
~list();
void add(T &obj);
T remove(int ID);
void print(ostream &out);
T search(int ID);

private:
node<T> *head, *tail;
};

template <class T>
class node
```

{
        public:
        node() {next = NULL;}
         //private:
    T data;
    node *next;
   };

```
template <class T>
list<T>::~list()
{
}
```

Comment: is list defined in your LinkedList.h ?

Comment: Also: reorder your includes! Standard library includes first, everything else follows.

Comment: What are the errors? Presumably, either `list`, `Account` or `Mortgage` isn't available in the global namespace. Start by including `<list>`, and make sure the other types are declared in the headers you're including, and add qualifications to them if they're in a namespace.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Could you explain why you'd want that ordering? I can't imagine how that would improve anything.

Comment: You're writing your own class called `list`, AND putting `using namespace std;` in the header file? Stop that at once!

Comment: Try `::list<Account> accList;` for educational purpose, then just drop that `list` class and use the one from `<list>`.

Comment: @Mike Well it’s probably unrelated to the problem at hand but I’d contend that it’s a general guideline. If there are no weird things in your headers and in standard library headers then it shouldn’t matter. But macros make this more complex: the user-defined headers can legitimately contain macros with the same name as standard library functions, for instance.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: OK; it's highly subjective, but I'd contend the opposite guideline: include your own headers first (and specifically as the very first include in the corresponding unit test) to check that they're self-contained, and to catch any weirdness like you describe ("legitimate" or otherwise) sooner rather than later. That way, people can use your headers without needing to know your personal rules about inclusion order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're defining your own class called `list` in the global namespace, and also putting `using namespace std;` in its header to dump the entire standard library into the global namespace. This means that you have two templates called `list` available in the global namespace, which will cause ambiguities and hence compile errors.

You should:

- avoid putting `using namespace std;` in source files
- never put it in headers, since it imposes namespace pollution on anyone who uses that header
- avoid putting your own declarations in the global namespace
- avoid giving your own declarations the same name as things in the standard library
- use standard library facilities rather than writing your own versions.